# User story for automatic updates

Tags: scrum

A user story for updating a rich client application could be "*As a user, I want to be able to update my application from the internet*".

But let's now assume that this update process is completely transparent. For example, the rich client could automatically connect to an update server and "refresh itself" without any user interaction".

In that case, how would the user story be written ?

According to the various articles I've read, it looks like what used to be a user story is now a technical requirements which should not be part of the product backlog but I may be wrong...

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "As a user I want that my application updates itself so I have always the latest version and I don't have to take care of it myself".

To me it's a totally legitimate user story as there is user value. The fact that the user doesn't have to perform any action doesn't invalidate the story. Lots of features are about "automatic" stuff.

Comment: I think that are right: although the automatic update process is not triggered by an explicit user action, it can still be considered as a user story.